# Relaese, Alloc and Nil an objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, null

Is this right way to handle memory?

Method 1: with no crash

```
 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220.0f, 7.0f, 57.0f, 35.0f)] ;

    button = nil;

    [button release];
```

Method 2: with crash

```
 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220.0f, 7.0f, 57.0f, 35.0f)] ;

   [button release];

   button = nil;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are incorrect. You should use the class method `buttonWithType`: to construct buttons. It will set the type as you specify. Buttons shouldn't be alloced/itited directly. (Maybe that's where the crash co es from, though it shouldn't)

The class method will return an autoreleased object, so you must not release it.

Despite of that (that is with other objects and ordinary alloc/init), the second way is correct; the first leaks.

Answer (score 1):

No need to set the variable, holding you allocated object, to nil. Just release it, if you don't need it anymore. That's it.

Comment: Setting the variable to nil is good practice, since when you don't, if you later send a message to the variable, you'll get a crash because you tried to send a message to a deallocated instance. If you set it to nil, you'll just get a nil result and the program will continue running. Try `NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"bla"];
    NSLog(@"rc = %d",[str retainCount]);
    [str release];
    str = nil;
    NSLog(@"rc = %d",[str retainCount]);` - this will run. Outcomment the `str = nil`, and you'll get a crash.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not correct, and case of memory leak.

The second method is used by all of most of us and it should not be crashed,

**Post the related code with the method #2.**

Comment: No. You should not use init with UIButton, but use buttonWithType: instead.

Comment: @ Eiko: it's not compulsory to use buttonWithType, it's just one of choice sometime requirement for developer. init method could also be used .

Comment: Apple's Doc say differently. And you cannot set the button type later. It is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Why you set ***`button = nil;`*** button value to nil, after ***`[button release];`*** you don't need to do that just do ***`[button release];`*** and your button will be released without any leaks.

Comment: Because somebody might have held on to that variable and still try to use it, which will result in a crash if you didn't set to nil; see my comment to unset's answer.